# Show same Dicom image header

Tags: dicom

I wonder if it is possible to have two different images with the same header. If so, can we display this two images in the PACS or otherwise which tags should be changed to display them?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. The issue is that Dicom requires every image to have it's own Unique UID stored in the header.

PACS systems commonly ignore newly received images if their UID is identical to one they already have in the database, so if you don't follow this part of the standard you probably don't get very far.

If you want to generate DICOM images, and you are unfamiliar with the standard, my advice is to use [OFFIS img2dcm](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/img2dcm.html) or a similar tool to convert them from normal images.

Answer (score 1):

Jan de Vaan is correct, you SHOULDNT have duplicate headers with different image bitmaps and that is 'guaranteed' by the unique SOP instance UID.  I've never seen a duplicate UID come from any modality. Saying that, there are sloppy applications with terrible UID implementations to generate the unique UID. There are teleradiology apps, secondary capture devices and other open source DICOM packages (for instance) that, typically on reset, could and do create a repeatable UID sequence. Many research labs get along fine with these. I expect you have one of these applications up the pipeline back to the source modality. If its messing up something as fundamental to DICOM as the UID, I would wonder what other wonderful things are happening.

If you must get these into the PACS, you would have to change the SOP Instance UID, which is not a recommended practice.

Comment: have you a reference to DICOM Standards that explicitly tells SOP instance UID will unique dicom files?
I have found them for Study (StudyInstnaceUID) and Series (SeriesInstanceUID) but not for files.